# Xcode cannot run using the selected device after upgrade to Xcode 5.0

Tags: xcode, build, ios-simulator, instruments

I upgraded to xcode 5.0 today. I then pressed play to run my project in the iOS simulator. This initially worked. Then I decided that I wanted to run the profiler. When I did that, I got the message:

```
Xcode cannot run using the selected device. 
Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device.
```

I looked at a couple past posts on this problem and decided to do a Clean and Build. Now I can no longer run in the profiler or the simulator. I consistently get the message:

```
Xcode cannot run using the selected device. 
Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device.
```

How can I resolve this?

Here are various settings:

My Deployment Target is 6.1

[image: My Build Settings Architectures looks like:]

I have also tried changing the deployment target to 7.0, but that did not work either

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It appears that the problem is not related to the architecture in the build settings as the error might suggest. Rather, I found that the problem seems to be related to the Build Options Compiler for C/C++/Objective C. I was using a gcc compiler (com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42) and Xcode 5 has marked this as unsupported.

If I change the compiler to apple's default Apple LLVM 5.0, the project builds and it can now run in the simulator. The downside is that I have a lot of compiler warnings from code related to cocos2D v1.0 source code. But, at least I have a way forward.

Comment: Thank you! This has me confused for hours. I actually switched to GCC in a previous version because of an LLVM bug.

Comment: This isn't a solution for me. My project was already set to compile using LLVM 5.0.

Comment: This worked for me in addition to setting CFBundleExecutable in the Info.plist to ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}

Comment: Very nice! You're saved my time ;)

Answer (score 34):

Please follow below step

1>Go to Project Build setting

2>Change compiler for c/c++/objective c as Default compiler(Apple LLVM 5.0) (see in below image)

[image]

Comment: Thank you it saves my time!! Above Answer also is the same but you made us easy with screen shot. @Chirs Alen

Answer (score 10):

I had to change compiler for Default compiler (Apple LLVM 5.0) at two places:

1. Build Settings > Build Options > Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C (change to LLVM)
2. Build Rules > Files *.mc using GCC (change to LLVM)

Hard to find because code compiles even if Build Rules point to an undefined compiler.

Comment: This happened to me when opening an old project after many years (also, schemes where missing). Thanks!!

Comment: I am using Xcode 5.1.1 and I do not see a FILES option under Build Rules. Is there another way to locate this second change?

Answer (score 7):

After inspecting all the build settings for 15 minutes, this worked for me (Xcode 5.0.2):

**Quit and restart Xcode**

Answer (score 6):

Check that the Executable File (also known as CFBundleExecutable) in the Info.plist file is set to **${EXECUTABLE_NAME}** as opposed to any hardcoded value. This will ensure that even if you change your project name or target name or scheme name, that it still works.

Answer (score 3):

This issue often occurs after duplicating targets on older projects.

Set the following in your Info.plist for the target:

```
Bundle Name = ${PRODUCT_NAME}
Bundle Display Name = ${PRODUCT_NAME}
Executable file = ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
```

Build and run with these settings, after a successful build they can be changed to anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: "Quit and restart Xcode". I recently updated something and the testing device on Xcode said: 'iDevice' not iPhone or iPod. So I restarted then my iPhone came back to the target list.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I changed  the value of the "Bundle name"-key in the Target Properties. Changing it back to "%{PRODUCT_NAME}" solved the problem for me.